# Ionic BUILD FAILED when running "ionic run android"

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I'm getting an inexplicable error when I run

```
ionic run android
```

I set everything up, installed all the packages it said I needed, plugged in my Android and verified it in `adb`, yet when I run ionic Android, I get:

```
C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp
λ ionic run android
Adding in default Ionic hooks
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js" "C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp"
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js" "C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp"
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat"""
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '9f55d3c0'.
Buildfile: C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Imray\Android Practice\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Imray\Android Practice\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 98 source files to C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaWebViewClient.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
    [javac]   location: package android.webkit
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaWebViewClient.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
    [javac]                                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
    [javac]   location: class CordovaWebViewClient
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaChromeClient.java:342: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    [javac]                                                                                                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class FileChooserParams
    [javac]   location: class WebChromeClient
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
    [javac]   location: package android.webkit
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private final ClientCertRequest request;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
    [javac]   location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public CordovaClientCertRequest(ClientCertRequest request) {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
    [javac]   location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaChromeClient.java:340: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaWebView.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    [javac]                                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaWebView.java:200: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(this, true);
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(CordovaWebView,boolean)
    [javac]   location: variable cookieManager of type CookieManager
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaWebViewClient.java:143: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaChromeClient.java:348: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable FileChooserParams
    [javac]   location: class WebChromeClient
    [javac] C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaChromeClient.java:341: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 12 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Imray\Android Practice\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Imray\Android Practice\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Imray\Android Practice\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant debug -f "C:\Users\Imray\Projects\appsnstuff\myApp\platforms\android\build.xml" -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Comment: Try to use latest BuildTools SDK . You are using 19. I see references to lollipop...

Comment: Could you update your android sdk and ionic frame work

Comment: I updated my Android SDK overnight to 21 and now it works. Weird

Comment: For me this still not works although I updated to API 21. I have all build-tool versions installed, 22.0.1 is currently used. I also used SDK Tools 24.1.2. Could you tell me which versions you use? i'm really getting crazy because of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my Android SDK overnight to 21 and now it works.